# Need to concatenate column values of same row

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

After so few Joins my View is like this

```
ID      Code

1       US
1       UK
1       GR
2       US
2       IN
3       US  
3       AF
3       RU
3       SA
```

Required Result :

```
ID  Code

1   US,UK,GR
2   US,IN
3   US,AF,RU,SA
```

I tried using FOR XML PATH.

But as the number of records are high in my table it is causing performance issue it is taking more than 20 minutes to execute

Comment: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Very informative I have to try the one that improves performance.

Comment: I tried XML Path, but execution time is the issue. T resolve this select into tableN from View and on that table I have applied XML path. But my table updates daily, to update the tableN again I have to create SQL job. which I wants to consider the last option. If there is any better way would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below query,

```
Select T.Id,
       Left(T.[Codes],Len(T.[Codes])-1) As Codes
From
    (
        Select distinct T2.ID, 
            (
                Select T1.Code + ',' AS [text()]
                From @T T1
                Where T1.ID = T2.ID
                ORDER BY T1.ID
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [Codes]
        From @T T2
    ) T
```

`@T` is your input table as in, `Declare @T as Table (ID INT, Code varchar(10))`

Comment: Assuming that you have added all necessary constraints to the table!!

Comment: I have split the column values into columns. This improved performance. For XML Path works but in my case performance is reduced if I use it

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below, Here you find different examples for your requirement:

[Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Comment: I'd say: someone stole link from my comment.

Comment: No @MaciejLos I didn't stolen the link, I actually not seen your comment before posting answer :)

Comment: @MaciejLos yes you are right I have seen your comment after your prompt. before 10 min I didn't noticed it :)